# Adding margin with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center  tags within a div but depending on what page you are on it can depend on how many tags there will be as it's for an image gallery. So i am trying to do it with Jquery.

Basically what i want to say is:

For every  tag add 5% to the margin.

Can someone point me in the right direction to do so. I was thinking of using the .size() to calculate the amount of  tags but not sure where to go then.

Thanks.

Comment: provide some code sample

Comment: Do you mean you want the margin to be 5% per item in the div (so 3 items == 15%), or just 5% margin on each item?

Comment: Ill post an answer but im not sure if it is what you need? I think you mean:

For x amount of tags add 5% margin to each?
Or x amount of tags * 5% = margin on a certain element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `*` selector

```
$("*").css("margin","5%");
```

However, for the safety purposes, you have to limit the use of such wildcard selector. There are lots of other ways you can select mass elements.

1. **Class Selecotors:** `$(".myclass')`
2. **Tag Selecotors:** `$("div")`
3. **Atrribute:** `$("input[type="text"]')`

Comment: i wouldn't suggest using the wildcard selector. This would add 5% to any element on the page. I would suggest using a selector based on classes for more control.

Comment: @SamWarren, OP does want `every tag`

Comment: Thanks Starx looks like exactly what i need. What if there are multiple one of page? As in.. The <a> tags are within a gallery div, but there might be multiple galleries on one page?

Comment: @starx, but this would also include the body of the page? I would personally never design a site like that. But its only advice. Im not saying your answer is wrong or anything :)

Comment: @SamWarren, That was a very good suggestion, I should have included the options for betterment. I have updated my answer, please review